# golang errors wrapping and checking

Tags: go

I'm trying to wrap package error with custom one, but `errors.Is` returns `false` when I checking for my wrapping error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type wrappedError struct {
    message string
    wrapped error
}

func (e *wrappedError) Error() string {
    return e.message
}

func (e *wrappedError) Unwrap() error {
    return e.wrapped
}

func newWrappedError(internalErr, wrapErr error) error {
    return &wrappedError{
        message: wrapErr.Error(),
        wrapped: internalErr,
    }
}

var (
    PkgErr = errors.New("third-party package error")
    MyErr  = errors.New("my error")
)

func main() {
    err := newWrappedError(PkgErr, MyErr)
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(err, PkgErr)) // prints "true" - ok
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(err, MyErr))  // prints "false" - PROBLEM, I need "true"
}
```

How to wrap error correctly to be able to check it via `errors.Is`?

Comment: Usually only a single error is wrapped when a new error value is created, not 2. You can achieve `err` to be both `PkgErr` and `MyErr` if `MyErr` first wraps `PkgErr`, and you wrap `PkgErr` like this: `MyErr  = fmt.Errorf("my error: %w", PkgErr)` and `err := fmt.Errorf("custom error: %w", MyErr)`, try it: https://go.dev/play/p/kXkcQFv6TNd

Comment: If this isn't what you want, please detail what you want to achieve and we may suggest a better solution.

Comment: I want to have pre-defined custom error for any errors returned by package function call.

For example, package function call may return 3 errors: `PkgErr1`, `PkgErr2` and `PkgErr3`. I want to wrap any of these errors into my custom `MyErr` and be able to check below both `errors.Is(err, PkgErr1)` and `errors.Is(err, MyErr)`